# Polymer 1.0 Creating custom Icons for radio buttons

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a requirement in which the paper-radio button needs to be replaced by custom icons and keeping the feature of the radio button intact.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well, if it's not circles, how would you highlight the *checked* state? Maybe an icon inside and wrapped with a big circle, which is only visible when it's checked?

Comment: I guess you''ll have to extend the  normal checkbox element and create a new element with different css for unchecked and :checked.